# QR reader app that interacts with an api

Tags: api, qr-code

I have created a database on a web server where there is a table called USERS and they have a flag whether yes or no, and each user is related to a QR code.
I will create a wifi network between a server and iPhone device.
Is there an iPhone app I can use, when I scan the QR code, it can interact with the database I created to turn the flag to ON? What API I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a mobile phone application reading a QR Code will start a browser to open the URL in the QR Code. (Similarly, it will call a phone number or prepare a text message or store a contact code, if the information in the QR Code is encoded correctly for those purposes.)

So, what you (rather simply) can do is make a web application to act on incoming HTTP requests. The QR Codes related to your users should contain the URL to that application, and it also contains some ID for the user. Once your application registers an incoming request with a valid ID, you update your database record.